# send email and notify-send do not work in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I configured crontab in order to send email and to display desktop notification. here after the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

ls /home/anis > /tmp/log.log
echo "---------------------$1-------------------" >> /tmp/log.log


info_and_email()
{
    logtime=`date "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"`
    notify-send "$1"
    echo "To:myemail@domain.com" > /tmp/report.txt
    echo "From:anysrc@domain.com" >> /tmp/report.txt
    echo "Subject: ------$1----- ($logtime)"  >> /tmp/report.txt
    ssmtp myemail@domain.com < /tmp/report.txt
}

info_and_email "$1"
```

If I run the script from CLI, the script is executed successfully and the notification is displayed and the email is sent, but if the script is executed from crontab, I can see the script is runnig with `ps`, but the email is not sent and the notification is not displayed.

What I m missing?

Comment: run `which ssmtp` and copy abosolute path for `ssmtp` or `type -P ssmtp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When run as cron, you don't have any environment set up.  Not even a PATH.  So it is probably not finding notify-send or ssmtp.

Either add a PATH at the beginning of your script, or give fully-qualified path names to commands that you issue.

Comment: _When run as cron, you don't have any environment set up. Not even a PATH._

Nope. All crons I've ever worked with set at least `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`. If `notify-send` and `ssmtp` were installed from distro packages (quite likely), the OP's script will find them just fine.

It's more correct to say that "`cron` sets up a *limited* environment". `man 5 crontab` to see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step should be to *check your email*. If any of your script's commands printed anything, especially errors, `cron` would've emailed all that output to the crontab's owner. (If needed, you can redirect that mail to user `xyz` by adding `MAILTO=xyz` to your crontab.)

To gain better insight on what's actually running, change the first line of your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

That turns on bash's *trace mode*, which shows you every command being executed. As mentioned above, when your script is run by `cron`, that execution trace log would be sent out via email.

Finally, note that all cron jobs run under a limited environment. `man 5 crontab` to see which environment variables are set to what values, and assume nothing else is set, period. (This plays a critical role in at least one of the utilities you're using.)

Now, to specific utilities:

---

`notify-send` uses the [D-Bus](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) messaging system to send notification requests to your desktop. That requires it to know how to connect to the D-Bus, er, *bus*, and that's done via a specific environment variable:

```
$ env | grep DBUS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Of course, that variable doesn't exist in a stock `cron` environment, so run the above command on your system, then copy that `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=...` line to your crontab. That adds the correct `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` setting to all your cron jobs' environment.

---

I have no experience with `ssmtp`, but [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp) says it has a verbose (`-v`) mode, so call it like:

```
ssmtp -v myemail@domain.com < /tmp/report.txt
```

in your script and see what it tells you.